# Converting String to a double in PHP

Tags: php, string, number-formatting

i need convert a string, like 37152548 to 371525,48 or 371525.48
i'm trying `number_format()` and `floatval()` but unsuccessful.

```
$var = '37152548';

$var = number_format($var, 2);

echo $var; // output 37,152,548.00
```

Comment: try dividing by 100 :)

Comment: Do you mean `$var/100`?

Comment: `number_format` returns a string.  `floatval` works fine; it returns a `float` of the value you gave it.  What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: This string comes from an import file, and I need to do calculations with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
$var = '37152548';
echo number_format($var / 100, 2, ".", "");
```

Output

```
371525.48
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working correctly. 37152548 is a whole number, so number format will just add in the commas. If you want the last 2 numbers to be on the other side of the decimal, you need to divide it by 100

```
$var = number_format($var/100, 2);
```

If the var was '371525.48', then it would format it the way you want. If you want it without commas, then try

```
$var = number_format($var/100, 2,'.','');
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP will convert your string to number anyway. As for the decimal place, since you say:

> i need convert a string, like 37152548 to 371525,48 or 371525.48

... well, divide by 100:

```
$var = '37152548';
echo $var / 100; //outputs 371525.48
```

---

If you want to be sure you have a number, then use [`floatval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) (as it returns a number intead of a string like [number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)):

```
$var = '37152548';
$var = floatval($var) / 100;
echo $var; //outputs: 371525.48
echo '<br>'; //new line
//And you can do calculations:
echo $var - 500; //outputs: 371025.48
```

---

floatval converts your string into a floating point variable. Note: PHP does not distinguish single and double precision, in fact [`doubleval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.doubleval.php) is just an alias of floatval.